# Drop down list in laravel form

Tags: html, laravel, dropdown, html-select

I have been working to build a laravel form and for the fields where text input is required I have successfully created. The following part works.

```
<fieldset>
<legend><span class="number">1</span> Personal Information</legend>

<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name *" value="{{old('name') }}">
        <div>{{ $errors->first('name') }} </div>

<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email *" value="{{old('email') }}">
        <div>{{ $errors->first('email') }} </div>

<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone *" value="{{old('phone') }}">
        <div>{{ $errors->first('phone') }} </div>
```

However, I want to make a drop down list of countries (and after this two or three other drop down lists). This is the HTML part of it. How do I use a drop down list in Laravel where the selected country will appear in the email I receive after the user submits the form?

```
<label for="nationality">Nationality:</label>
<select id="nationality" name="nationality">
  <option value="select_nationality">*</option>
  <option value="india">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="india">Albania</option>
  <option value="india">Algeria</option>  (includes all the countries in the list)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a dropdown with selectable countries. After user selected this( together with entering the other fields) you send this to laravel and want to mail a copy of their selected/entered results. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That is what I want.

Comment: do you know how to use mailables in laravel?

Comment: I have used mailables successfully on a simple form with name, email and phone number (all with text fields). Now I want to know how to use drop down lists.